# Calling private functions from another private function of the same class

Tags: c++, class

Can I call private functions from another private function of the same class, for example:

```
Class A {
public: 
  double a; 
  double b; 
  wp(a , b);

private: 
   wp1(x);
   wp2(y);
};
A::wp(a,b){
  a = wp1(x);
}
A::wp1(x){
  x = wp2(y); }
```

I know that in order to access private functions you need to call them from public functions, but can I call private functions from other private functions of the same class?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes. What happened when you tried to run it?

Comment: You could get your code to compile and see for yourself.

Comment: _"I know that in order to access private functions you need to call them from public functions"_ Who taught you so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can. You can *always* call a `private` function and access all class member data from any function within the class. That's what `private` does.

(Note that you can *also* access the `private` members of an instance of that class passed into a member function of that class. Although surprising at first, it's how you implement overloaded operators, copy constructors, &c.)

Comment: To clarify, the deal with `private:` (and also `protected:`) relates to a client's perspective. If you call a function from outside the class (including from a derived class) you may not have access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can because the function is within the class itself

Answer (score 0):

Private members of a class can be accessed by methods of the class and it's friends. It is irrelevant if that methods are private, public or protected by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Your example should work, if I didn't miss a detail. So to answer your question, it is possible to access a private function from another private function of the same class.